# How do I choose which edge to augment first in bipartite matching algorithm?

Tags: python, recursion, graph, bipartite

I am writing a ford fulkerson algorithm to match nodes in a bipartite graph. Currently the algorithm is recursive, and bipartite graphs are stored as dictionaries of lists.

i.e.

`bpGraph = {0: [0, 2, 1], 1: [2, 1, 1], 2: [0, 0, 2]}`

means that node 0 in U can move to nodes [0, 2, 1] in V and so on.

The recursive nature of my function means that my algorithm looks for an available node in V for each node in U, and assigns it if the node in V is free, it does this over all of the nodes in U. If there is a node in U that wants to go somewhere in V it checks recursively whether or not there is an alternative node in V for a node currently assigned to that node if that exists.

This is great, however it always returns the same matching. I want to be able to find all the possible maximum matchings. Does anyone have any ideas of how to implement ford fulkerson algorithm without using recursion? where I could then declare which edge I want to augment first, rather than doing it in a loop?

The only solution I can think of is to find the edges in my bipartite matching graph, and cycle through all possible matchings greedily and check whether or not they correspond to max flow at the end. However, this seems like a poor solution.

thanks in advance,

S

Comment: Why do you feel that removing recursion will solve your problem?  What you describe is a matter of persistence and ordering, neither of which is impaired by recursion.

Comment: Any recursive process can be done with iteration, and vice versa.  Search on general conversion methods; FF is straightforward.

Comment: How does declaring the edge you want to attack first (which you can do simply by ordering the edges in the graph) give you the control you seek?  You still get only one result.  If you plan to cycle through several (or all) edges, then you're most of the way to the iterative solution already.

Comment: You're asking to identify *all* optimal solutions without traversing the entire solution space.  What properties of the problem do you imagine will permit this?  Memoization (dynamic programming) is an obvious short-cut, but you seem to be looking for more.

Comment: How is it that you map a node in U to a node in V more than once?  For instance, you have the entry `2: [0, 0, 2]`; what does int mean to have U2 mapped twice to V0?

Comment: Recursion forces the program to reconsider a node placement in V if there is an alternative place for it to go. I've labelled the nodes with numbers in both sets U and V, which is why ordering the edges is difficult to abstract in my code. I'm not sure what memoization is yet, but thanks I will look this up. the edges correspond to discrete bits of information, i.e. more than one bit at a starting a particular node could have the same destination.

Comment: Memoization is a technique in dynamic programming -- the basic idea is to remember partial results so that you don't repeat computations.

Comment: Reconsidering node placement is not specific to recursion; you can do the same with iteration.  Any iterative selector will do the job, such as `for v_node in bpGraph[u_node]:`  I can't get particularly specific, since you haven't posted any sort of code.